# JUnit Testing for User Interface with Database Integration in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, passwords

I've been told to test a user interface via JUnit Testing. However, how can I go about testing aspects of the user interface such as login credentials? For example, I want to test what happens if someone enters in the wrong password. Right now, the password is verified by comparing the entered password with the hashed password in the database. I am unsure how to test different password parameters. Can this even be done using JUnit testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest Junit + DBunit + spring-test

The testing problem can be resolved mocking the database.
In my point of view, It's a little complex to explain here, so can you look into this example? https://bitbucket.org/dperezcabrera/fest-swing-test

I think it can help.